# PATINDEX in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark

I have this statement in sql

```
Case WHEN AAAA is not null then AAAA
     Else RTRIM(LEFT(BBBB, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', BBBB) - 1))
     END as NAME.
```

I need to convert this to spark sql. I tried using indexOf, but it doesn't take the string '%[0-9]%. How do i convert the above statement to spark SQL. please help

Thanks !

Comment: Provide some input and output data. It would easier then to get tested answer.

Comment: The input data would be SOUTH TEXAS SYNDICATE 454C and the output should be SOUTH TEXAS SYNDICATE                                                                        Few more examples                                                                                                       SANDERS 34-27 #3TFH would be SANDERS                                                                  K. R. BRACKEN B 3H  would become K. R. BRACKEN B

Comment: Hey @ Sujat
 Please check if my answer below solves your problem. It it does please accept it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code to do this in scala spark. I used udf to do this.
Edit : Assuming string needs to be cut from first occurrence of number.

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(("SOUTH TEXAS SYNDICATE 454C"),
  ("SANDERS 34-27 #3TF"),
  ("K. R. BRACKEN B 3H"))
  .toDF("name")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
val getIndexOfFirstNumber = (s: String) => {
      val str = s.split("\\D+").filter(_.nonEmpty).toList
      s.indexOf(str(0))
    }
spark.udf.register("getIndexOfFirstNumber", getIndexOfFirstNumber)

spark.sql("""
select name,substr(name, 0, getIndexOfFirstNumber(name) -1) as final_name
from temp
""").show(20,false)
```

Result ::

```
   +------------------------------------+----------------------+
   |name                                |final_name            |
   +------------------------------------+----------------------+
   |SOUTH TEXAS SYNDICATE 454C          |SOUTH TEXAS SYNDICATE |
   |SANDERS 34-27 #3TF                  |SANDERS               |
   |K. R. BRACKEN B 3H                  |K. R. BRACKEN B       |
   |ALEXANDER-WESSENDORFF 1 (SA) A5 A 5H|ALEXANDER-WESSENDORFF |
   |USZYNSKI-FURLOW (SA) B 3H           |USZYNSKI-FURLOW (SA) B|
   +------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Manish. But it did not work for few conditions like ALEXANDER-WESSENDORFF 1 (SA) A5 A 5H and USZYNSKI-FURLOW (SA) B 3H. Can you help me please?

Comment: @Sujatha What should be the output of these two names. I am guessing the logic is to identify first digit in the string and cut the from that index. Please confirm.

Comment: @Sujatha   
I have edited my answer with the logic that name colum needs to be cut before the first occurence of number. Please check.

Comment: @Sujatha 
Please accept it as answer and upvote the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Manish answer I build this, it's more generic and was build in Python. You can use it on spark sql as well
The exemple is not for numbers but for the string *DATE*

```
import re
def PATINDEX(string,s):
    if s:
        match = re.search(string, s)
        if match:
            return match.start()+1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return 0
spark.udf.register("PATINDEX", PATINDEX)
PATINDEX('DATE','a2aDATEs2s')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to remove the leading zeroes using Databricks or Spark SQL.

```
REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE('0000123045','0',' ')),' ','0')
```

**EXPLANATION:**

- The first replace function replaces the zero with empty space.
  **Example : '    123 45'**
- The LTRIM function removes the empty space from the left.
  **Example : '123 45'**
- Then the third replace function replaces the empty space with zero.
  **Example:'123045'**

***Similarly, you can use the function with RTRIM for removing the trailing zeroes accordingly.***

**Do an upvote if you like my answer.**
Thanks